# What procedures does the FIA take when there are thunderstorms?

Tags: rules, formula-1

For the 2022 Formula 1 Season, Miami is hosting one of two races in the USA.

Miami, and Florida as a whole, has a bit of a reputation for quite severe thunderstorms, and particularly whereby sporting events have had to be postponed because of such weather. [1](https://www.local10.com/sports/2018/09/09/dolphins-game-delayed-multiple-times-after-lightning-strikes/) [2](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2014/jun/08/england-honduras-world-cup-warm-up-match-report)

Although there may be lightning in the air, that may not necessarily mean the track conditions are unsuitable for racing, for example any rain that comes with the thunderstorm could be negated by Wet tyres, and a thunderstorm does not necessarily mean heavy rain. However, given that the drivers are going around in an electrically conductive box, and that fans are usually situated on uncovered temporary stands (read: scaffolding), lightning could be seen as a danger.

Are there any specific set of procedures for the Race Director to follow in the case of thunderstorms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the official FIA sporting regulations document listed on the FIA site, there's not a specific set of procedures for the scenario that you are painting.

But if this scenario were to happen, it would be at the discretion of the race director on the day to either keep the practice/race going, or Abort/Red Flag the session.

The logical option would be to follow the same procedures to restarting a wet-weather session.

Here are some steps that may be taken as per the Sporting regulations document:

> **4.4.6** Should it become necessary to stop any practice session because the circuit is blocked by an
> accident or because **weather or other conditions make it dangerous to continue**, the clerk of the
> course will order red flags to be shown at all marshal posts and the abort lights to be shown at the
> Line.
> When the signal is given to stop all cars must immediately reduce speed and proceed slowly back
> to the pit lane. In order to ensure that drivers reduce speed sufficiently, from the time at which
> the “RED FLAG” message appears on the official messaging system until the time that each car
> crosses the first safety car line when entering the pit lane, drivers must stay above the minimum
> time set by the FIA ECU at least once in each marshalling sector (a marshalling sector is defined as
> the section of track between each of the FIA light panels).
> All cars abandoned on the track will be removed to a safe place.
> At the end of each practice session no driver may cross the Line more than once.

I also think that section **4.8.14 (c)** of the sporting regulations may also apply during the restarts, but it's too long for this post, so I've added a link to the 2022 sporting regulations below.

[2022 FORMULA 1 SPORTING REGULATIONS](https://www.fia.com/sites/default/files/2022_formula_1_sporting_regulations_-_iss_1_-_2020-05-27_0.pdf)